# Lack of brightness in Filmic Log encoding system when exporting radiance HDR sequence

Tags: animation, color, filmic-blender

I am running blender 2.83.
I wanted to export a Radiance HDR sequence with the color management system set to Filmic log. But when I brought the radiance sequence to after effects, it looks really dark, has a really high contrast and has a lot of artefacts in the highlights. I wanted to know how it happened. Hoping for a positive reply:)

Comment: Have you tried OpenEXR? 32bit ... Also there can be an issue how your scene is lighted, so probably some screenshots and simplified blend file would be helpful to let us see.

Comment: I've never dealt with radiance as format, but I do know the following: an image encoded in a color space will look wrong when viewed in the wrong color space. You would need to instruct afterfx to interpret the image using a reverse lut for log (linearizing the data back to space referred) before compositing. Radiance, as far as I know, is a format that seems to be falling out favor, and most users prefer OpenEXR, that keeps your information linear. If you must use log, then use Tiff as container, and linearize back in afterfx.